# Generating a scaffold when using a routing scope?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my routes I have:

```
scope module: 'admin', constraints: {subdomain: /admin/} do 
  resources: users
end
```

This allows me to have my whole admin backend constrained to a subdomain and my paths look like "users_path" rather than "admin_users_path".

I.e. the admin can go to "admin.example.com/users" rather than going to "example.com/admin/users"

When I generate a scaffold I type:

```
rails generate scaffold admin/foobar
```

This creates a foobar object inside the admin folder, but this scaffold generates everything with paths like "admin_foobars_path" rather than "foobars_path".  The paths are generated incorrectly because I'm using a scope module in my routes.

Is there any way to get the scaffold generator to generate links inside a folder (admin) without adding the "admin" prefix to all the variables and paths that it generates?